# Issue with NSFontPanel

Tags: cocoa, nsfontmanager, nsfontpanel

I have an application where I user need to modify style (font, size, bold, back and fore colors,...)
How can I load the initial style in the FontPanel and get the new attributes after user validation?

I tried a lot of different things but without any success.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `setPanelFont:isMultiple:` to set the initially selected font.

Use `[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] setSelectedAttributes:isMultiple:` to change the initially colors; the dictionary keys are `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `@"NSDocumentBackgroundColor"` for the colors and `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` and `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` for the styles.

When the font changes the `changeFont:` method of the delegate instance will be called.

Ditto styles: `changeAttributes:` method.
And text & doc colors: `setColor:forAttribute:` method.

To get the new attributes in the changeAttributes method:

```
NSDictionary * newAttributes = [sender convertAttributes:@{}];
```

Comment: I was using the wrong attributes and target was set but not delegate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2:

```
NSFontPanel.shared.setPanelFont(myNSFont, isMultiple: false)
    NSFontManager.shared.setSelectedAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue: myNSColor], isMultiple: false)
```

You can find a list of all attribute keys [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey) - the old style constants have not been deprecated, but as of 10.13, no longer work.

To be notified of changes if you want to change, say, the contents of a label that doesn't have a field editor attached, you need to set NSFontManager.shared's target and action, and register for NSColorPanel.colorDidChangeNotification (NSColorChanging does not fire when the ColorPanel is opened from the FontPanel).